# inserting primary key value from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql

i am new to mysql ,

i have an application in which i am getting dynamic values from mysql table say "TABLE A" into dropdown box, and want to insert this dropdown box value into another table  say "TABLE B", while inserting want to insert related "primary key" value from "TABLE A" into "TABLE B".

can anyone give any sugessions or idea of how to do this..
thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: What exactly is your question about?

Comment: in brief want to insert auto increment values of one table to other

Comment: i am able to get the values dynamically from mysql table to dropdown box.. even i can insert those selected values from dropdown box into another table, but not able to insert related auto increment values into another table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding ,

i hope you 'd have the drop down values,

On insert you should use sub queries to select the id of values using where clause

Example:

```
   Insert into Table B (name ,id )values('name',(Select id from table A where Value==""))
```

[Document for reference](http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Select-Clause/Insertstatementwithsubquery.htm)

Correct me if  'm wrong

Comment: hi thanga thank you for replying, u almost correct..  but the value (in where clause) its self is a value of dropdown box. so how to get those dynamic values into where caluse.

Comment: can i write or modify like the below query

Insert into Table B (name ,id )values('name',(Select id from table A where Value=="$name"))

were "$name" holds the value of dropdownbox..

Comment: thank you thanga, ur query is working fine with small modifications in where clause